# jQuery - How is this timeline made?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't figure out how to make an interactive timeline with javascript. Does anybody know how the timeline on top of this website is made?
http://www.ivillage.com/getting-ready-try/6-t-124335

For a screencap: http://gyazo.com/9aa8295ac65a8b54796a34df7ea35b6c.png

Thanks a  million!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use flot to make something like that quite easily

[Flot Project page](http://code.google.com/p/flot/)